# Why Markov Chain Monte Carlo allows sampling from a large class of distributions and scales well with the dimensionality of the sample space?

Tags: sampling

How can I understand "Markov chain Monte Carlo allows sampling from a large class of distributions and which scales well with the dimensionality of the sample space"